# Sorting a linked list from text file python

Tags: python, linked-list

I have store around 600 data into a linked list by using python. Some of my example data is:

```
1735A,Bench Power Supplies,Not Required
BA6011,Battery Testers,Yes
8616,DC Electronic Loads,Yes
```

I want to create a sorting algorithm based on data above. My question is what is the suitable sorting algortihm to use (mergesort/quicksort/insertionsort/etc.) to sort the middle part of data in ascending order? (....,Bench power,....../......,DC electronic,....). It is possible to sort based on the middle word using that algorithm?

Comment: You can sort the list using any attribute that you have in the data

Answer (score 0):

Mergesort is suitable for your case and the comparison key is the second element.

But if space is not a limitation and you want to make your code simple and neat. My suggestion is not doing sorting on the linked list.

- Read data from the text file as a normal list

```
[(1735A,Bench Power Supplies,Not Required),(BA6011,Battery Testers,Yes),(8616,DC Electronic Loads,Yes)]
```

- Sorting on a normal list (built-in sorted function)
  `sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[1])`
- Convert it to a linked list